# How do you check for an existing lead, contact, person account by email address?

Tags: duplicate-management

From a Custom Object record creation I'd like to check if an existing lead, contact or account exists via Email match.

Please does any one have a step by step solution?

Comment: My suggestion would be create before trigger on custom object and run query to check on lead,account etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use duplicate management feature provided by sales-force. You can create duplicate and matching rule for your Custom Object where you can match your new record with existing Account, Lead or Contact based on Email. At the time of saving your new record, message will be shown to you containing list of existing matching duplicates records from Account, Lead or Contact.
For this, you have to create separate duplicate and matching rule for each object to which you want to match custom object's record.

Refer these links for step by step creation:
1.
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/10/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_data_quality_duplicate_prevention.pdf
2. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_standard_lead_rule.htm&type=0

Once you set up rules then Error message will be shown like :
[image]

[image]